# I want to get a key as input and a comparison of key value in if condition

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement, keyerror, key-value-store

It shows KeyError: ('Black in Black', 8.5)

```
album_rating={"Black in Black":8.5,"Believer":6,"SmackTac":7,"You":9}
a=(input("Enter the name:"))

For a in album_rating.items():
    if(album_rating[a]>8):
     print("This album is Amazing!")
    else:        
     print("Try a different album")
print("Welcome")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a couple of things which need fixing here. Firstly you name your input variable `a` but then use that to loop over your dictionary.

Secondly `dict.items()` returns a list of key value pairs e.g.

`[('Black in Black', 8.5), ('Believer', 6), ('SmackTac', 7), ('You', 9)])` so `a` will never be found in the dictionary because you are comparing a string to a list hence the `KeyError`.

If you want to loop over the keys of a dictionary specifically then you should use `dict.keys()`. Alternatively you can use a `try-except` block to catch any `KeyErrors`.

```
album_rating={"Black in Black":8.5,"Believer":6,"SmackTac":7,"You":9}
a=input("Enter the name:")

try:
    album = album_rating[a]
    if(album_rating[a]>8):
        print("This album is Amazing!")
    else:        
        print("Try a different album")
except KeyError:
    print ("Album does not exist")
```

OR

```
album_rating={"Black in Black":8.5,"Believer":6,"SmackTac":7,"You":9}
a=input("Enter the name:")

if a in album_rating.keys():
    if(album_rating[a]>8):
        print("This album is Amazing!")
    else:        
        print("Try a different album")
else:
    print ("try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of that for loop you introduced? I think you don't need it.
Does the code below work for you?

```py
album_rating = {"Black in Black": 8.5, "Believer": 6, "SmackTac":7, "You": 9}
a = input("Enter the name:")

if album_rating[a] > 8:
    print("This album is Amazing!")
else:
    print("Try a different album")
```